# Non-Ugly Way Convert a MUMPS $H formatted date/time to an Excel 2016 date/time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, mumps, excel-2016

I am looking for a non-ugly way to convert a MUMPS formatted $H ("63868,62327" is 11/12/2015 at 17:18:47) date/time into an Excel 2016 compatible format date/time format.  I came up with the following, but it's ugly:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,(SEARCH(",",A1)-1))-21548) & MID(NUMBERVALUE((1/86400)*MID(A1,(SEARCH(",",A1)+1),5)),2,6))
```

While this does work, it is definitely ugly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)-21548+ MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,99)/86400
```

Comment: Thanks much.  Works well.  That and choose the following date format:

Comment: That and choose the following date format in Excel 2016 "Format Cells:-->Number (tab)-->Category-->Date--Type:":

Date: 3/14/15 13:30

Answer (score 0):

Just curious to know if you are able to use `$zdt($h)` instead of `$h` on the Caché side. This will do that exact same conversion for you.

Furthermore, if this is a solution, then there are extra parameters to specify the format. The one you asked about is the default: `$zdt($h,1,1)` or simply `$zdt($h)`.

$zdt has date formats between 1-15 and time formats between 1-10.

This format is as follows:

```
$zdt([n],[d],[t])
```

Where n is a mumps formatted number, d is the date format 1-15 and t is the time format 1-10.

Comment: Thanks, that's good information on the Cache/Intersystems side of things.  I was looking specifically for the $H format as it is stock standard for all MUMPS implementations.